# How do I change the signature of a method I have overriden from my interface that I implemented onto the concrete class I'm using?

Tags: java

For example

```
//This is part of Comparable Interface:
public int compareTo(T other);//T being any class/type of parameter

//This is part of my own interface: 
public void beeper(Object what);

//This is part of my own concrete class which implements both of the above interfaces
public int compareTo(Country other)//Java allows this...
{
  //code stuffs....
}
public void beeper(String what)//This does not work...
{
  //Code stuffs....
}
```

How would you make an abstract method that allows you to change the method signature like compareTo does?

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterized type.

Parent interface :

```
public interface ParentClass<T>{
  void beeper(T what);
}
```

Child class :

```
public class ChildClass implements ParentClass<String>{
  public void beeper(String what){ 
    // your impl
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Btw, there is no public abstract in the interface class's methods since every method in an interface is already public abstract. :)

Comment: Right :) At first, I had write a class. Then, I changed it into an interface to stick more with your question, but I didn't  remove useless modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

`Comparable` is using generics; you can, too:

```
public interface Beepable<T> {
    void beeper(T what);
}
```

Your code would do this:

```
public class StringBeeper implements Beepable<String> {
    public void beeper(String what) { // implement here }
}
```